# Написать функцию, формирующую одномерный массив, состоящий из квадратов отрицательных элементов, лежащих выше главной диагонали квадратной матрицы

Tags: c++

Написать функцию, формирующую одномерный массив, состоящий из квадратов отрицательных элементов, лежащих выше главной диагонали квадратной матрицы В. Написать пример обращения к этой функции

Не подскажите, где ошибка? Не все элементы выводятся

```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <cstdlib>
  #include <ctime>
  const int SIZE = 4;
  void elementynadDiagonal(int arr[][SIZE], int diag[], int a[])
   {
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE-1; i++)
{
    for (int j = i + 1; j < SIZE; j++)
    {
        diag[i] = arr[i][j];
        if (diag[i] <= 0)
            a[i] = diag[i] * diag[i];
    }
}

}
int main()
{
srand(time(0));
int arr[SIZE][SIZE] = { 0 };
int diag[SIZE] = { 0 };
int a[SIZE] = { 0 };
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
    {
        arr[i][j] = rand() % 21 - 10;
        std::cout.width(4);
        std::cout << arr[i][j];
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
std::cout << "Squred elementy nad diagonal " << std::endl;
elementynadDiagonal(arr, diag, a);  
   for (int i = 0; i < SIZE-1; i++)
    {

            std::cout.width(4);
            std::cout << a[i];

    }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Во всех циклах `SIZE-1` уберите -1

Comment: Также у вас только отрицательные, а вы и 0 захватили diag[i] < 0